# jQuery validate not working on multiple fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a search results page in which I have a search field at the top of the page and another at the bottom.

I'm using the jQuery Validate plugin (BTW, I'm very new to jQuery) but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since it's not working with one function, so I have to create two.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="search-wrapper-large">
  <form id="top-search" method="GET" action="">
    <input name="topsearch" id="topsearch" class="largesearchfield" type="text">
    <button type="submit" title="Search">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>

<p>...search results...</p>

<div class="search-wrapper-large">
  <form id="bottom-search" method="GET" action="">
    <input name="bottomsearch" id="bottomsearch" class="largesearchfield" type="text">
    <button type="submit" title="Search">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
//Search field validation
$('#top-search').validate({
    invalidHandler: $.watermark.showAll,    
    rules: {
        topsearch: { required: true, minlength: 3 }
    },
    messages: {
        topsearch: "Please enter a valid search term (at least 3 characters)."

    }           
});

$('#bottom-search').validate({
    invalidHandler: $.watermark.showAll,    
    rules: {        
        bottomsearch: { required: true, minlength: 3 }
    },
    messages: {
        bottomsearch: "Please enter a valid search term (at least 3 characters)."       
    }               
});
```

1. Is there a way to have both validations in one single function?
2. Would I have to wrap both fields in one single < form > element then?

Thanks for any advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can target two elements with a single selector by separating each identifier with comma</strike> In order to have separate error output labels, jQuery Validate must be called once for each form.

Your initialization method is partially incorrect because the 'messages' option of the `validate()` method expects an object with a message for each rule, rather than a single message applied to all rules.

Assuming you change the name of the fields 'topsearch' and 'bottomsearch' to both be 'term' (or any matching name), you can store the 'options' parameter of jQuery Validate in a variable and then simply invoke `validate()` with the 'options' variable once for each form. The following code should work:

```
var options = {
    invalidHandler: $.watermark.showAll,    
    rules: {        
        term: { 
            required: true, 
            minlength: 3 
        }
    },
    messages: {
        term:  {
            required: "Please enter a valid search term (at least 3 characters).",
            minlength: "Please enter a valid search term (at least 3 characters)."
        }       
    }               
};

$("#top-search").validate(options);
$("#bottom-search").validate(options);
```

Here's a jsFiddle for the above, minus the invalid handler: http://jsfiddle.net/C6LdW/

Comment: Well, it didn't really worked as needed, for 2 reasons: 1. The bottom search field's error label appears in the top search field. Here's a screen shot of what I'm saying: http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/1104/screenshot1252011101758.png. 2. The actual error for the bottom search field is not coming up. As you can see in my code, I changed the 'minlegth' message to "test", but only one message is coming up. Here's a screen shot of the jQuery code: http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/6126/screenshot1252011102323.png.

Comment: What I need is to have each search field display its own error label in the right spot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ricardo sorry for the inaccurate information, I have done some testing and reposted a solution that *really* should work.

Comment: Awesome! It worked perfectly :). Thanks a lot Nathan. Now I can use the same variable in an include file and just call the validate() method with just one line, like you did at the bottom. Great! :D